# glide thumbnail for ImageView with fixed width but height wrap_content

Tags: android-layout, thumbnails, placeholder, android-glide, image-loading

I have been trying to implement a feed App like Instagram or Facebook. ImageViews have match_parent width (screen width) and wrap_content height.

The code I have used...

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView)
        ;
```

That results into loading thumbnail first. The thumbnail is very small in size. I was expected that the thumbnail will display a faded image with the original image height.

Without thumbnail, the ImageViews do not populate any image (when loading) and then suddenly the original images comes into picture. I cannot use any place holder image as the height of the place holder image may not match the actual image to be loaded, makes it a bad user experience.

I have also tried...

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(null)
                .into(imageView)
        ;
```

But it is not working! I was wondering how the Instagram App does those fade in loading with images (with **original image height**)?

I have looked into various websites including the Glide Github issues and stack overflow, but unable to find any solution! I have already wasted about 6 hours of my day. What is the way out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use override attribute:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageURL)
        .override(18,18)                
        .thumbnail(0.1f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(imageView);
```

Also as Instagram is owned by Facebook it might be the case that they use Fresco library (not sure though).